# to compare the memory usage between the use of the static array and java.util.ArrayList in a sorting operation

Tags: java

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  long  totalM = rt.totalMemory();
  long  currentM;

  int  []n = new int[10000];
  System.out.print("10000 ints used: ");
  System.out.println(totalM - rt.freeMemory());
```

Its not working. We cannot use long for calculation?

Thanks in advance, Please give me some suggestions

Comment: "Its not working" What does it do instead? And of course you can use longs for calculation.

Comment: Can't you use something like jmh instead? It is pretty good at monitoring things like that

Comment: You're initializing totalM to totalMemory(), but subtracting freeMemory(). Is that really what you want? I'm guessing you want to initialize totalM to freeMemory() so you can see the change.

Comment: @blm, `int []n` is the same thing as `int[] n`. Both are valid declarations of `n` as a reference to an array of `int`s.  The former is rather unconventional though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I'm an idiot sometimes :-), I definitely know that, the odd formatting threw me off, I've never seen it written that way, but obviously it will work as you say.

Comment: @blm, no worries.  I can claim my own share of goofs.  In any event, your observation about `freeMemory()` vs. `totalMemory()` is well made.

Comment: `freeMemory()` is a fairly useless value, because there may be uncollected garbage taking up space. An `int[]` of 10000 elements take up 4 bytes per `int` plus the overhead of an array, so 4 * 10000 = 40000 bytes + overhead. Overhead depends on JVM but is likely around 16 bytes, so negligible by comparison.

Answer (score 2):

*Answering the implicit question in the title:* What is difference in "memory usage between the use of the static array and java.util.ArrayList in a sorting operation".

In Java 8: **None**. This is because the sort is delegated to the `ArrayList` class, which sorts the backing array directly using `Arrays.sort()`.

In Java 7 and below, the list is converted to an array, the array is sorted, and the result is put back into the list. So, memory is **doubled** for the array, plus whatever extra memory is need by the sorting operation itself, which depends on the version of Java.
This is also what happens for `LinkedList` in Java 8.